# Problemas al compilar con sass

Tags: css, css3, sass, scss

tengo un problema al compilar mi archivo .sass, la cuestión es que cuando ejecuto la compilación por primera ves el se ejecuta y guarda normal pero al hacer otro cambio muestra el error que aparece en la imagen adjunta, estoy usando un subtema de bootstrap barrio. muchas gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No todo el mundo puede de ver imágenes, por ello pon tu error como texto.

Comment: No creo que sea un tema de SASS ni CSS. ¿Podrías añadir un poco más de información? ¿Cómo compilas el SASS a CSS?